# Unable to extract Result Set

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, oracle19c, liquibase-hibernate

I am not new to hibernate but facing some strange issue with it.
My Java base application build upon Java 8, JSF, Hibernate 5.1 and Oracle 19C data base and liquibase.

Adding a property into to existing table is pretty straight forward task but I am facing some problem after adding a boolean into to existing table, Hibernate is not able to extract result, one more thing I wanted to add here is that the same things work with Oracle 11G version of data base.

Please find the bellow code snippet details for the same.

---

Entiry.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date startProcessingOn;
    
    @Column(name = "is_grouping_allow")
    private boolean grouping;

    @Column(name="allow_manual_cash_update")
    private boolean allowManualCashUpdate; // Newly added boolean property
     
    .......

}
```

db.changelog.xml

```
<changeSet id="KXX-10724" author="ravi.sapariya">
<addColumn tableName="person">
<column name="allow_manual_cash_update" type="decimal(1)" defaultValueBoolean="false">
<constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>
</addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

After executing above DB change log table contain extra column with **NUMBER(1,0)** data type.

When I was trying to star my server it's giving me some generic error saying **could not extract ResultSet** with some other Entiry which I had never change. The change which I had done in Person Entity but it say unable to load Alert Entity. Although Alert Has-a relationship with Person.

logs

```
15:52:24,455 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet

15:52:24,460 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)

15:52:24,461 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)

15:52:24,462 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)

15:52:24,463 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at krt.dao.AlertDao.queryAlerts(AlertDao.java:164)

15:52:24,464 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at krt.dao.AlertDao.loadAlerts(AlertDao.java:137)

15:52:24,465 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
15:52:24,466 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

15:52:24,467 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

15:52:24,467 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

15:52:24,468 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)

15:52:24,468 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,470 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)

15:52:24,470 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)

15:52:24,471 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)

15:52:24,472 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)

15:52:24,472 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,472 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)

15:52:24,473 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,474 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)

15:52:24,474 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,475 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)

15:52:24,475 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,476 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)

15:52:24,476 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,477 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)

15:52:24,478 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)

15:52:24,478 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,479 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)

15:52:24,479 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,480 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:185)

15:52:24,480 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:364)

15:52:24,480 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:144)

15:52:24,481 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,481 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)

15:52:24,482 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)

15:52:24,482 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)

15:52:24,483 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,483 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)

15:52:24,483 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,484 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)

15:52:24,484 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,485 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)

15:52:24,485 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,485 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)

15:52:24,486 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,486 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)

15:52:24,487 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,487 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)

15:52:24,488 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,489 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
15:52:24,490 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,490 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)

15:52:24,490 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,491 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
15:52:24,491 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,492 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)

15:52:24,492 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:619)

15:52:24,492 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)

15:52:24,493 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,493 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)

15:52:24,493 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)

15:52:24,494 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)

15:52:24,494 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)

15:52:24,494 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at krt.dao.AlertDao$$$view55.loadAlerts(Unknown Source)

15:52:24,495 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

15:52:24,495 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

15:52:24,495 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

15:52:24,495 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

15:52:24,496 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:411)

15:52:24,496 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)
15:52:24,503 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,503 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
15:52:24,504 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,504 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237)

15:52:24,505 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:362)

15:52:24,505 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:144)

15:52:24,506 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,506 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)

15:52:24,506 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
15:52:24,506 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
15:52:24,507 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,507 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
15:52:24,507 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,509 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
15:52:24,509 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,509 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
15:52:24,509 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,510 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
15:52:24,510 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
15:52:24,510 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
15:52:24,511 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
15:52:24,511 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
15:52:24,511 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,512 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
15:52:24,512 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,514 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)

15:52:24,514 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,515 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)

15:52:24,515 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)

15:52:24,515 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)

15:52:24,516 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)

15:52:24,516 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at krt.ejb.AlertXmlDao$$$view29.loadAlerts(Unknown Source)

15:52:24,516 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

15:52:24,516 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

15:52:24,517 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

15:52:24,517 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

15:52:24,517 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:411)

15:52:24,517 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)

15:52:24,517 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)

15:52:24,518 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:68)

15:52:24,518 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)

15:52:24,518 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at krt.ejb.AlertXmlDao$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.loadAlerts(Unknown Source)

15:52:24,519 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at krt.AlertStore.loadAlerts(AlertStore.java:298)

15:52:24,519 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at krt.AlertStore.loadDBAlerts(AlertStore.java:120)

15:52:24,519 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at krt.AlertStore.onStartup(AlertStore.java:112)

15:52:24,520 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

15:52:24,520 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

15:52:24,520 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

15:52:24,521 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

15:52:24,521 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:96)

15:52:24,521 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,522 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doLifecycleInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:122)

15:52:24,523 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:111)

15:52:24,523 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,524 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)

15:52:24,525 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)

15:52:24,525 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)

15:52:24,525 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,525 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:53)

15:52:24,526 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,526 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)

15:52:24,526 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,527 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)

15:52:24,527 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,527 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:105)

15:52:24,527 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,527 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
15:52:24,528 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,528 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInNoTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:216)
15:52:24,528 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.never(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
15:52:24,529 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:62)
15:52:24,529 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)

15:52:24,529 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)

15:52:24,529 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
15:52:24,530 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
15:52:24,530 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
15:52:24,531 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
15:52:24,532 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.StartupCountDownInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupCountDownInterceptor.java:25
15:52:24,534 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:127)
15:52:24,534 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:141)

15:52:24,534 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)

15:52:24,535 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

15:52:24,535 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

15:52:24,535 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

15:52:24,536 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)

15:52:24,536 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)

15:52:24,536 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)

15:52:24,537 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

15:52:24,537 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

15:52:24,538 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
15:52:24,539 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)

15:52:24,539 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
15:52:24,539 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
15:52:24,539 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
15:52:24,540 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
15:52:24,540 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434)
15:52:24,540 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186)
15:52:24,541 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
15:52:24,541 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)

15:52:24,551 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
(ServerService Thread Pool -- 72)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
```

I am using org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect.
Any Help would be highly appreciated as I am stuck in this issue for 2-3 days.
AlertDao contain just simple query so that not causing any issue if i remove newly added field form Person.

Comment: Updating Person Entity with String type and relevant update as VARCHAR into data base is working but facing issue with only boolean or int type.

Comment: Also Person Entity contains total 40 columns including this newly type(20 are String type, 15 are boolean,5 Date)

Comment: are you sure liquibase `decimal(1)` added field of `Number(1,0)` type in oracle?

Comment: I have never used liquibase but this [article](https://dba-presents.com/index.php/liquibase/29-liquibase-3-3-x-data-types-mapping-table) suggest that decimal maps to decimal in oracle.

Comment: Can you add the DDL of the person table in your DB?

Comment: @code-mechanic Forget about liquibase, event i have tried to create new column in DB with NUMBER(1,0) but it didn't work.

Comment: Its very hard to tell what problem you might be facing, try changing the primitive type to wrapper object Boolean or try removing it and adding integer or something, you have to check by hit and trial. Its very difficult to suggest anything at this point.

Comment: One more thing i observed here is that when i set default 0 into database to that column, server is failing but without default value (i.e null) in that case it's working.